# Qt How i can filter more than one columns?

Tags: qt, model, combobox, filter, proxy

In my Qt project i am using sql, table view, and qsortproxymodel to filter columns.The problem is in that, that i can filter only one column.For example, from category "CATS", and category "DOGS", i can only filter items for only one of the categories.I want to see both items, from dogs and cats. 
How i can do that?

My source code is:

```
void Animals::on_comboBox_currentTextChanged(... QString &arg1) // class 
{ 
    ProxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(3); 
    ProxyModel->setFilterFixedString(ui->combobox->currentText());
} 

void Animals::on_comboBox_2_currentTextChange... QString &arg1) // class with letters 
{ 
    ProxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(4);
    ProxyModel->setFilterFixedString(ui->combobox_2->currentText());
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is not possible to do that without subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel

Answer (score 4):

You should subclass QSortFilterProxyModel and reimplement filterAcceptsRow
example from Docs:

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
         const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
 {
     QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
     QModelIndex index1 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent);
     QModelIndex index2 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 2, sourceParent);

     return (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(filterRegExp())
             || sourceModel()->data(index1).toString().contains(filterRegExp()))
            && dateInRange(sourceModel()->data(index2).toDate());
 }
```